# Как вставить переменную $url в поле перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript, php, html, php5

```
<?php
$filename = "text.txt";  
{ 
// Разбиваем строку по разделителю :: 
$data = explode("::",$line); 
    // В массив $temp помещаем имена и пароли 
    // зарегистрированных посетителей 
    $temp['name'][$i]     = $data[0];  
    $temp['password'][$i] = $data[1]; 
    $temp['email'][$i]    = $data[2]; 
    $url['url'][$i]      = trim($data[3]); 
    // Увеличиваем счётчик 
    $i++; 
} 
?> 
<HTML><HEAD> 
    <META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; 
    URL=$url'><--!?-->
</HEAD></HTML>
<?php 
     } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
     $filename = "text.txt";  
     // Разбиваем строку по разделителю :: 
     $data = explode("::",$line); 
     // В массив $temp помещаем имена и пароли 
     // зарегистрированных посетителей 
     $temp['name'][$i]     = $data[0];  
     $temp['password'][$i] = $data[1]; 
     $temp['email'][$i]    = $data[2]; 
     $url['url'][$i]      = trim($data[3]); 
     // Увеличиваем счётчик 
     $i++; 

 ?> 
 <HTML><HEAD> 
     <META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; 
     URL=<?php echo $url; ?>'><--!?-->
 </HEAD></HTML>
```